# Unity Add Component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having some trouble in unity with adding a script I wrote to a cube **in runtime**. I have seen lots of other people asking about this but they seem to have fixed it.

**Code:**

```
            // Insert
            GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            // Appearance
            cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.yellow);
            Shader transparent;
            transparent = Shader.Find("UI/Default");
            cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.shader = transparent;
            //
            //
            // Postioning
            //cxcxcxcxc
            cube.transform.position = new Vector3((xpos), (ypos), zpos);
            cube.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(90, 0, 0);


            var myScript = cube.gameObject.AddComponent<CoinCollect>();
```

This code creates a cube, adds shaders and positions it. I would now like to add a script to it which I have created called "CoinCollect" which is **done with the last line of code.** This doesn't spring up any errors but when the game is run the script isn't added. Could someone help? I looked at the documentation but it mainly showed what I was doing.

Comment: "cube" is already your gameObject. I don't think this will fix the issue. --> cube.AddComponent...

Comment: Yet again doing that gave me no errors however the script wasn't added.

Comment: Look in your scene for the new gameobject and see if `CoinCollect` is attached to it.

Comment: @Andrew I would request you to comment below my answer as to which part solved it. It would help other users hunt down the precise issue.

Comment: The code I posted was in an if statement which had some issues so it was not specific to the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the script name and class name within the scripts are equal. Other than that, there is nothing wrong with your code. Even the official docs do it in the same way:

[**Unity Docs:**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html)

> ```
> // Adds the sphere collider to the game object  
> SphereCollider sc = gameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
> ```

And [this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/641159/not-work-in-runtime-addremove-c-script.html) on `Unity Answers` suggest the same way to add scripts:

> AddComponent and GetComponent use the name of the class in the script, not a path to the script.
>
> ```
> AddComponent("DestroyOnTouch");
> ```
>
> Or preferably:
>
> ```
>  AddComponent<DestroyOnTouch>();
> ```
>
> As this will give you a compile time error if the class cannot be found, rather than a runtime error.

Also:

- How do you know that the script doesn't work? Try a simple `Debug.Log()` and verify, it might be some error in the script itself.
- Does the code you posted in the question ever get executed? Where have you placed it? In a script? Then check that it is attached to some `gameObject` or gets called. Also, you might consider checking whether the method in which you wrote the code gets called.
- To check the above, place a `Debug.Log("The main script ran");` in the same code block and run your game. Then, check the console in Unity.

Comment: Oh thanks, I realised the coin script wasn't named correctly and due to some other code the line didn't actually run. I should probably check that next time. Thanks :)